# Change default calendar used by Google Calendar from "Phone" to my Google account

Tags: sync, google-calendar

When I create an event on my phone, by default it is created in the "Phone" calendar, unfortunately:

[image]

Which means the event is not synced to google.com/calendar.
I have to switch manually every time.

**QUESTION:** How to change the default calendar?

- "Sync Calendar" is enabled.
- In the app I have no "Settings > General Settings > Default Calendar" setting.
- "Home > Settings > Applications > Calendar Storage > Clear data" did not solve the problem.
- Android 4.1.2 with Google Calendar 201308023.
- I'd rather stick with the official app, except if it is unfixable.